# mean of n rows by grouping another column in r

Tags: r, group-by, aggregate, mean

I have a dataframe and I need to calculate Mean of x for every n rows
by grouping Name, lets say n= 3
Sample dataset df:

```
 Name     X  
  A      3.1     
  A      2.5    
  A      3.6  
  A      3.4  
  B      4.6  
  B      1.8  
  B      3.4
```

For every name, mean of first 3 rows, then next 3 rows,
 if in the end < 3 rows for a name, mean for those 1 or 2 rows.

So far I've been able to group for the 3 rows or names separately.
Any help on how to imply those two together would be appreciated.

```
## by grouping 3 rows##
final1<-aggregate(df$X,list(rep(1(nrow(df)%/%n+1),each=n,len=nrow(df))),mean)[-1]  

##by grouping name##
final2<- df %>% group_by(Name) %>% summarise(value=mean(df$X))
```

Desired Output is:

```
  Name      X     
   A      3.066  
   A      3.400  
   B      3.266
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You could try adding a secondary grouping variable in the veins of `df %>% group_by(Name) %>% mutate(idx = ceiling(seq_len(n())/3)) %>% group_by(idx, add=T) %>% summarise(value=mean(X)) `.

Comment: I had already tried grouping by 2 variables, wasn't working. Thanks for helping though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use the `row_number` function, while also using `group_by` to come up with a solution:

We first create a variable called `row_num_mod` which takes the `row_number mod 3`. We can then group by `row_num_mod` and `Name` to find out which instance the observation belongs to.

We can use `row_number` again so that we're essentially ordering the different values mod 3.

```
dat %>%
    group_by(Name) %>%
    mutate(row_num_mod = row_number() %% 3) %>% 
    ungroup() %>%
    group_by(row_num_mod, Name) %>%
    mutate(row_num2 = row_number()) %>% # which instance of x mod 3 is this?
    ungroup() %>%
    group_by(Name, row_num2) %>%
    summarise(Mean = mean(X))

   Name row_num2     Mean
  <chr>    <int>    <dbl>
1     A        1 3.066667
2     A        2 3.400000
3     B        1 3.266667
```

#### Clarity

To demonstrate the fields we've added, here's what the data looks like after adding `row_num2`:

```
   Name     X row_num_mod row_num2
  <chr> <dbl>       <dbl>    <int>
1     A   3.1           1        1
2     A   2.5           2        1
3     A   3.6           0        1
4     A   3.4           1        2
5     B   4.6           1        1
6     B   1.8           2        1
7     B   3.4           0        1
```

#### Data

```
dat <- read.table(text = " Name     X  
  A      3.1     
  A      2.5    
  A      3.6  
  A      3.4  
  B      4.6  
  B      1.8  
  B      3.4 ", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: I think this could be shortened to `dat %>% group_by(Name) %>% mutate(ind = cumsum(row_number() %% 3 == 1)) %>% group_by(ind, add = TRUE) %>% summarise(Mean = mean(X))`
`

Comment: Great! This is exactly what I was looking for. Didn't realize mutate() could be used for this!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be to use `%/%` and `n()` instead of `%%` and  `row_number`:

```
dat %>% 
  group_by(Name) %>% 
  mutate(ind = 0:(n() - 1) %/% 3) %>% 
  group_by(ind, add = TRUE) %>% 
  summarise(Mean = mean(X))
## Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
## Groups: Name [?]
## 
##    Name   ind     Mean
##   <chr> <dbl>    <dbl>
## 1     A     0 3.066667
## 2     A     1 3.400000
## 3     B     0 3.266667
```

Answer (score 0):

Using rollapply from the zoo package. We can use the `by = 3` argument to move the rolling windows in steps of 3, and we can use `partial = TRUE` to include groups smaller than 3 which are left at the end. I demonstrate here using data.table for grouping, although you could equally well use dplyr or base functions to group:

```
dt[, rollapply(X, 3, mean, by = 3, align = "left", partial=T), by=Name]
#    Name       V1
# 1:    A 3.066667
# 2:    A 3.400000
# 3:    B 3.266667
```

**data and libraries:**

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)
dt= fread ("Name     X  
A      3.1     
A      2.5    
A      3.6  
A      3.4  
B      4.6  
B      1.8  
B      3.4 ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution with `data.table`:

```
library("data.table")
dt <- fread(
' Name     X  
  A      3.1     
  A      2.5    
  A      3.6  
  A      3.4  
  B      4.6  
  B      1.8  
  B      3.4 ')
dt[, n3:=gl(.N, 3, length=.N), by=Name]
dt[, .(X=mean(X)), by=.(Name, n3)]
# > dt[, .(X=mean(X)), by=.(Name, n3)]
#    Name n3        X
# 1:    A  1 3.066667
# 2:    A  2 3.400000
# 3:    B  1 3.266667
```